# SwiftUI repeating TabView

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview

From [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-scrolling-pages-of-content-using-tabviewstyle) article, I took this code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Text("First")
            Text("Second")
            Text("Third")
            Text("Fourth")
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page)
        }
    }
```

This works for a paging view, but I want it to repeat the pages so when it gets to the last item, the next scroll will get to the first item again and repeat.

Is there a SwiftUI easy way to achieve this? Any idea how to get this to work as described?

Comment: There is no built in way to do it.

Comment: @loremipsum do you have an idea how to get it done?

Comment: I don't have a specific sample but if you google infinite scrolling or infinite tabview you will find many resources and approaches, this is very common